# How many triangles with integral side lengths are possible, provided their perimeter is $36$ units?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, triangles

How many triangles with integral side lengths are possible, provided their perimeter is $36$ units?

My approach:

Let the side lengths be $a, b, c$; now,

$$a + b + c = 36$$

Now, $1 \leq a, b, c \leq 18$.

Applying multinomial theorem, I'm getting $187$ which is wrong.

Please help.

Comment: Did you take the triangle inequality into account?

Comment: Yes, I did. When one side is of $1$ unit, then the max possible values for other two will be $18$ i.e. $(1, 18, 18)$

Comment: $$18+18+1\neq36$$

Comment: You didn't say how you did it. Possibly permutations of $a,b,c$ are considered to give the same triangle; did you account for that (after all drawing the the triangle elsewhere or in a different orientation does not count as giving a different triangle either, I suppose)?

Comment: I don't see how the multinomial theorem, which gives expansions for such things as $(x+y+z+t)^n$, is relevant to this problem.

Comment: I counted the number of positive integer solutions $\{a,b,c\}$ to $a+b+c=36$; it is 108. But of course they are not all triangles.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I forgot to remove cases after getting 187.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The number of triangles with perimeter $n$ and integer side lengths is given by [Alcuin's sequence](http://oeis.org/A005044) $T(n)$. The generating function for $T(n)$ is $\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$. Alcuin's sequence can be expressed as

$$T(n)=\begin{cases}\left[\frac{n^2}{48}\right]&n\text{ even}\\\left[\frac{(n+3)^2}{48}\right]&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

where $[x]$ is the nearest integer function, and thus $T(36)=27$. See [this article by Krier and Manvel](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690701) for more details. See also [Andrews](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2320420), [Jordan/Walch/Wisner](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321300), [these](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3219089) [two](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691493) by Hirschhorn, and [Bindner/Erickson](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.119.02.115).

Comment: What if the perimeter is 18? Then T(N) isn't an integer.

Comment: Did you notice the use of the nearest integer function?