# How many non-congruent triangles with perimeter 11 have integer side lengths?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

How many non-congruent triangles with perimeter 11 have integer side lengths?

I failed to solve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you fail.

Comment: You just need find $a + b + c = 11$ with $a < b+ c; b< a+c; c<b+a$

Comment: Yes I have realized that. But then I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Just assume $a<b<c$, then proceed from $c<a+b$.

Comment: This is a contest question and has a valid solution which fleablood has demonstrated below. Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170319/how-many-triangles-with-integral-side-lengths-are-possible-provided-their-perim?rq=1 shows a formula for determining this type of problem. Hence it is surely not off topic on the basis "This question is missing context or other details".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality says two sides must be larger than the third.

Let $a \le b \le  c$

So $a + b > 5.5$ and $c < 5.5$ and $c = 11 - a - b$

If $a = 1$, then $b > 4.5$ so $b \ge 5$ and $c \le 5$ so: $a = 1;b=5;c=5$

If $a = 2$ then $3.5 < 4 \le b $ and $c \le 5$ so $a = 2; b= 4; c =5$.

If $a = 3$ then $2.5 < 3 \le b$ and $c \le 5$ so if $b = 3$ then $c = 5$ and if $b=4$ then $c = 4$.

If $a = 4$ then $1.5 < 4 \le b$ and $c \le 3$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks.  [link] http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170319/how-many-triangles-with-integral-side-lengths-are-possible-provided-their-perim?rq=1   also helped to understand it in depth.