# To find number of ways of solving $x + y + z = 12$, with $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 6$, using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I am learning generating functions so I tried to solve the below question using generating functions.

Number of ways in which value of three variables add up to 12.
$x + y + z = 12$ and  $0 \leq x,y,z \leq 6$.

To solve this question, we can form a generating functions as :
$$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^3$$ and find the coefficient of $x^{12}$.

The above function can be written as:
$$\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^3$$ 
How do I find coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the above expression?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset  mathematics on this site.

Comment: $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^3 = x^{18} + 3 x^{17} + 6 x^{16} + 10 x^{15} + 15 x^{14} + 21 x^{13} + 28 x^{12} + 33 x^{11} + 36 x^{10} + 37 x^9 + 36 x^8 + 33 x^7 + 28 x^6 + 21 x^5 + 15 x^4 + 10 x^3 + 6 x^2 + 3 x + 1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170319/how-many-triangles-with-integral-side-lengths-are-possible-provided-their-perim/170325#170325 ?

Comment: @Surb Here it was just cube so you were able to do it manually. What if it was to the power 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^3=(1-x^7)^3(1-x)^{-3}=(1-3x^7+3x^{14}-x^{21})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n,$

so the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is given by $\displaystyle\binom{14}{2}-3\binom{7}{2}=28.$

Comment: What if the power  of (1- x^7 ) would have been 5 or 6 ? How would you reduce that ?

Comment: Since we're only interested in the coefficient of $x^{12}$, you can just use the first two terms $1-5x^7+\cdots$ or $1-6x^7+\cdots$.